# HTC One M7 - Unauthorized in adb

Tags: android, sdk, adb, root

After 10 hours spent, it seems that I need to remove /data/misc/adb/adb_key file and restart the phone. But how can I do it if phone is unrooted and adb has no access?

It's unrooted HTC One M7 Att. I've tried reinstalling drivers many times and reinstalling sdk. I plugged and unplugged usb, changed ports, turned on and off debugging. Nothing helps and rsa dialog doesn't come up. I've also deleted adbkey files in .Android folder on Windows.

I've connected another HTC One and it worked smoothly. So, problem in the phone.

Help?

Comment: Try http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: And Settings->Developer Options->Revoke USB debugging authorizations doesn't help? In addition to trying a different cable/usb port/PC.

Comment: There is not such option on this phone, I've looked.. I've tried 4 different ports.

Comment: _There is not such option on this phone_ --- Which option exactly? You don't see "Developer options"?

Answer (score 0):

If your device appears in `adb devices` output (even as "unauthorized") - your drivers are fine. Also there's no need to reinstall the whole SDK - just make sure you have updated `platform-tools` package to the latest version.

1. unplug your device
2. kill adb (or just reboot your PC)
3. start adb
4. make sure your device is unlocked at the idle (launcher) screen
5. plug your device back in

you should see the authorization dialog now.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did it few times to no avail.

I ended up borrowing friend's mac, and all works fine. I'm thinking the reason must be in adbkey, either on my windows somewhere or on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

that means that you need to confirm the connection on the device (in your case the htc m7).
A Dialog should be displayed on the device (e.g Image below) when you connect to your device.

[image: confirm adb Connection on phone]

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative.....
You can connect it using adb wireless app and debug your apps wirelessly...:)
following is app link.....
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry&hl=en